# Excel showing black stripes and boxes

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office-2016

So, whenever I open a new excel tab or open an excel file, it shows this. 
[image: The black stripes get worse when scrolling or even when typing my text will turn black]

Comment: Try Disabling Hardware graphics acceleration in Excel -> File -> Options --> Advanced --> Display setting.

Comment: Do you have a Radeon card and did you recently update the driver?

Answer (score 0):

This typically happens for two reasons: graphics glitch (maybe reinstall/update drivers for GPU will be enough) or Excel settings. In the latter case, you should check that screen updating and formula cell updating are enabled in the Formulas section. Are you or have you used any Excel files that contained VBA scripts? These can change settings that mess up the graphics rendering. They typically have an 'm' in the extension, such as *.xlsm.

Going back to the first case, I've seen this many times (graphic glitches). Excel has been using direct graphics rendering since around 2007. My past solutions were to reinstall libraries related to graphics. FIrst, before doing anything, restart and see if it goes away on its own. You may wish to start with graphics drivers (NVidia or AMD?), then try reinstalling office, then look at Microsoft's framework libraries, and finally if it really is an issue, maybe even Windows itself (worst case, but I don't recommend going this far).

Important question for you though. Was it like this when you first used Excel? or did it changed recently? It's also possible that another installation recently has caused some issues for you. If you don't remember, you can look at the programs installed by going to Control Panel. To be generic for all versions of Windows, just look for the icon with "Programs" in the name. Windows 7 and newer will show you when programs were installed if a proper installer was ran.